# 新ナビゲーション・デザイン

Tags: サポート, デザイン

Stack Overflow英語版と同じように当サイトのヘッダーを更新します：

> [image: 新しいデザイン]

来週の木曜日か金曜日に適用する予定ですので、適用してから問題点・疑問点等があれば、ご教示ください。

Comment: 関連:  ["We're Soon to be A/B Testing Some Changes to the Top Nav"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/337745/5989200) -- Stack Overflow Meta

Comment: 関連: ["Has the top bar redesign met its goals?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/349204/5989200) -- Stack Overflow Meta

Answer (score 6):

トップページの一番上のバーから「ツアー」と「ヘルプセンター」へのリンクが無くなりました。

リンクが完全になくなったわけではなく、トップページのフッターの小さい文字からはリンクされていますし、また、質問・回答するときには右側にヘルプセンターへの案内が出ています。

どうしてこのようにしたのか疑問だったのですが、[本家Stack Overflow Meta への投稿によると](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/349386/5989200)これも改善の1つだそうです。

本家Stack Overflowではこのようにヘルプセンターへアクセスしたかどうかの統計が出ているようなので、スタック・オーバーフローの方でも似たような統計が出せるのであれば見てみたいなあと思いました（可能でしょうか？）。

Comment: 現在ヘッダーのA/Bテストを行う予定ですので、結果によってヘルプのリンク等が入る可能性もあります。そのテスト結果について後日共有させていただきます。

Answer (score 3):

新ナビゲーションになって使いにくくなった点が一点あります。
スニペットの最大化を行った場合にスニペット内のコンテンツがナビゲーションの下に
隠れてしまいます。

画像２枚目参照

よろしくお願いします。

[image: スニペット例]

[image: 全画面で表示させた時]

Comment: 開発者・デザイナーと確認中です。

Comment: ちなみに、本家Stack Overflowでも同様の事象が発生します。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 開発者が改善して、今後のビルドに適用されるようです。明日まだ発生していたら、ご教示ください。指摘ありがとうございます！

Comment: 迅速なご対応、ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

まだ慣れていないだけかもしれませんが、右上の受信箱に赤いアイコンが出てるのに、しばらく気づけませんでした。
問題が場所なのかアイコンのデザインなのかはわかりませんが、もう少し目立つようにしていただけると、個人的にはうれしいです。